# Unzipping a docx that is password protected with JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, zip, docx

Ran into a problem with password-protected docx.
For regular docx, unzipping is not a problem, and I'm specifically searching for the XML holding the document's labels - found in `$filename/docMetadata/Labelinfo.xml`
For password-protected docx, this file is still present, and is unencrypted, in a different path - `$filename/DataSpaces/TransformInfo/LabelInfo.xml`
Unzipping this file is not a problem on my machine, but I run into a problem with all the JS unzipping libraries - 'end of central directory not found'.

Is there any JS solution to this?

Tried numerous NPM zip-handling libraries, always getting the same error.